# In C#, what's the safe way to do generically convert a primitive to a string for serialization?

Tags: c#, string, serialization, deserialization

I'd like to generically serialize a class/struct in C#. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume class/struct can only be one level deep (no structs of structs).

Here's what I'd like to write

```
System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = obj.GetType().GetFields();
foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo info in fields) {
    object fieldValue = info.GetValue(obj);
    if (fieldValue != null) {
        builder.Append(fieldValue.ToString());
    }
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately as far as I can tell that won't work because `ToString()` is culture sensitive. In other words for a `Single` it might output `12.345` or `12,345` depending on the culture settings.

Is there some other non-culture sensitive `ToString` I can call for primitive types?

Also, is there a non-culture sensitive generic string to object function. I'm currently using

```
object value = System.Convert.ChangeType(string, someType);
```

But that's also apparently culture sensitive. :(

Comment: using `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter` you can then use `ConvertToInvariantString` on the value of the Type

Answer (score 4):

For ChangeType, there's an [overload which accepts an IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can call:

```
System.Convert.ChangeType(string, someType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some other non-culture sensitive ToString I can call for primitive types?
>   Also, is there a non-culture sensitive generic string to object function

IMHO, the simplest solution is to just format the string and pass a formatter. That way you don't have to explicitly handle each individual value separately.

For example:

```
foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo info in fields) {
    object fieldValue = info.GetValue(obj);
    builder.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", fieldValue);
    ...
}
```

This will work with any object that overrides `ToString()`, though of course not all may necessarily implement `IFormattable`. For those, whatever their normal `ToString()` override does will be used (which may still be culture-dependent). The C# primitives will all work this way though.

Note: as Stuart pointed out, the composite formatting system will handle a `null` value automatically (returning the empty string), so you don't even need that check if you use the above.

In other words, the above does essentially the same thing as checking for `IFormattable`, using it if it's supported, and falling back on `ToString()` otherwise. It's just less code to write. :)

Comment: Very neat solution, note that the composite formatting system handles null values as well by [outputting an empty string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx) - "If the value to be formatted is null, an empty string ("") is returned.", so that's even less code!

Comment: Yup, that's true. Wasn't even thinking about that part, but you're right...I can get rid of that `null` check as well. And I think I will. :)

Comment: And the other direction?

Comment: Sorry...I didn't see any request for deserialization in the question. Unfortunately, deserialization is fundamentally different. You're not dealing with an object instance (i.e. one that can provide a polymorphic parsing implementation), and you have to know what type you're dealing with to deserialize. On the bright side, that means you can always just pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to the appropriate parsing/deserialization method you're using to reverse the serialization operation above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about numbers and dates, you want `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

But it sounds like you're talking about structured data, and you want to be able to *deserialize* this data as well.  Therefore, you should be thinking about the *format* of that data in its string representation.

XML and JSON are popular choices for serialization formats.  In modern .NET applications, XML is typically implemented with [the `XDocument` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), or with [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx).  JSON is best achieved with [the JSON.NET library](http://json.net).

Comment: Thanks but for various reasons I can't use the JSON.NET library nor the XML stuff.

Comment: @gman - inventing brand new serialization formats is harder than it looks, so at least consider why existing ones done the way are done :) If you don't like verbosity of text formats - maybe existing binary one like https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/ would do?

Comment: Please give me some credit. I would much rather use an existing solution. I looked. They didn't fit my needs. For example. JSON.NET requires LINQ features in order to handle polymorphic types. But I'm using C# .NET 2.0 in Unity3D which doesn't support LINQ. My needs are small. I'm not trying to invent an entire 100% serialize anything and everything solution. At the same time, if there's a generic C# way to handle primitives I'd like to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Plutonix comment this is the answer I choose

```
System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = obj.GetType().GetFields();
foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo info in fields) {
    object fieldValue = info.GetValue(obj);
    if (fieldValue != null) {
        System.Type type = fieldValue.GetType();
        string s = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(
            type).ConvertToInvariantString(fieldValue);
        ...
    }
}
```

The opposite of

```
string s = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(
               type).ConvertToInvariantString(fieldValue);
```

Is

```
object o = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(
               type).ConvertFromInvariantString(s);
```

[This test seems to work](https://gist.github.com/greggman/875a4f0a8f826bc0bfdd)